# How do I add my client key and client secret into this python scripting to where it passes?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to access data from a website in which I have an API key and secret for using python. I am having trouble connecting to this API. I am positive that my API key and secret are correct.

My following code is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = 'https://website/$export'
payload = {'******Client_Key*********':'**************Client_Secret*****************'}
r = request.get(url, params = payload)
```

This is the error:
<Response [401]>

{'issue': [{'code': 'exception',
'details': {'coding': [{'code': 'Invalid Token',
'display': '',
'system': 'http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/operation-outcome'}],
'text': ''},
'severity': 'error'}],
'resourceType': 'OperationOutcome'}

Comment: Normally it belongs to the 'header'

Comment: The API should have some kind of documentation that explains how to authenticate. It’s impossible for us to help without knowing more about the API.